# Fill the Material Dashboard Component dynamically with Data

Tags: angular, angular-material, dashboard

I have **@angular/cli": "~7.3.8"** and **"@angular/material": "^7.3.7"**
installed. I started a project and added Angular Material to it. After that i installed a Nav Component and called it "mynav" via :

```js
ng generate @angular/material:nav mynav
```

I generated also a Dashboard component from the Angular Material Schematics and called it "mydash" via :

```js
ng generate @angular/material:dashboard mydash
```

The question now, how to add content dynamically (for example Data with ChartJS, that will be updated every time a chance occurs) to the card element in the Dashboard.

The cards elements are organized via a function in the dash.component.ts that consumes the array. Here is the automatically generated code in both files :

**dash.component.ts :**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Breakpoints, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dash',
  templateUrl: './dash.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dash.component.css']
})
export class DashComponent {
  /** Based on the screen size, switch from standard to one column per row */
  cards = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
    map(({ matches }) => {
      if (matches) {
        return [
          { title: 'Card 1', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
        ];
      }

      return [
        { title: 'Card 1', cols: 2, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 2 },
        { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
      ];
    })
  );

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
}
```

**and dash.component.html :**

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <h1 class="mat-h1">Dashboard</h1>
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="350px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            {{card.title}}
            <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
              <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
              <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
              <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
            </mat-menu>
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
          <div>Card Content Here</div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Dynamic Component section on the Angular docs? https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader